# Login functionality in HTML page

Tags: php, html

I have created a HTML page which takes user-id and password from user and then check there validity through database. Till now i was directing them to another page after successful login. But now i want to update same page after login. Just like www.facebook.com ; when we are NOT logged in its asks for user-id and password, but if we are login our profile contents are displayed on the same page i.e. facebook.com. What i was doing; directing it to page "login.php" which of course you can access without login.

For example there is a page "movies.com" which allows user to watch some movies after login; before i was just directing them to another page say "successful_login.com" after they login. It was a funny approach, but was working for my college assignments.

PS. Am just a noob, sorry if i asked something funny.

```
<?php
if(mysql_connect("localhost","root","")==false)
{
  die ("Connection Failed");
}
mysql_select_db("data");
if($_POST) 
{
  $id=$_POST["email"];
  $pwd=$_POST["password"];
  $pwd=hash( 'sha256', $pwd);
  $sql=mysql_query("SELECT* FROM admin_data WHERE id='$id' AND pass='$pwd'");
  if($sql)
  {
   header("Location: login.php");
 }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" /> 
  <title>
    HTML Document Structure
  </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>

  <form method="POST">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <div class="inset">
      <p>
        <label for="email">Login</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="password">PASSWORD</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
      </p>
    </div>
    <p class="p-container">
      <span>Forgot password ?</span>
      <input type="submit" name="Login" id="Login" value="Log in">
    </p>
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: From the page you have redirect to (accessControl.php) you can (if the user is logged in) redirect to the home page. The home page need to be .php and you can check for example sessions vars.

Comment: Your code is open to SQL injections and the `mysql_*` functions you are using are deprecated.

Comment: When you call the mysql_query function, that will return with a resource. You will redirect the user even if there was no user like that. Use `SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt ....` and then after `mysql_query` fetch the row, and check that. And after `header('Location: ...');`  call a `die()` or `exit();`

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 Take the example www.facebook.com ; when we are NOT logged in its asks for user-id and password, but if we are login our profile contents are displayed on the same page i.e. facebook.com. What i was doing; directing it to page "login.php" which of course you can access without login.

Comment: That was very helpful but i didn't complete idea of "Store there credential in the session". Please explain it a little bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the `session` variable you need to start `session` at the top.

`session_start();`

Now store the `email` value in the session in here.

```
if(mysql_num_rows()>0)//It was originally if($sql)but I am using mysql_num_rows
//The reason for saving the value in the session here is this. 
First you want to make sure that user have valid credential to log in.
  {
$_SESSION['email']=$id
   header("Location: login.php");
 }
```

In your form you can do something like this

`session_start();`//Start the session at the top so you can use the session variable.

then simply use `if` `else` statement.

```
if($_SESSION['email']==TRUE)
{
$email=$_SESSION['email'];
//Now you can run the query by using $email to fetch the record of the user.
}
else 
{
//Show them a form or redirect them to another page.
}
```

**Note**:`mysql` is deprecated and is going to be dropped soon. Use `mysqli` or `P.D.O`